# Seeing if a request succeeds from within a service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker, fetch-api

I have the following code in my service worker:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  var fetchPromise = fetch(event.request);

  fetchPromise.then(function () {
    // do something here
  });

  event.respondWith(fetchPromise);
});
```

However, it's doing some weird stuff in the dev console and seems to be making the script load asynchronously instead of synchronously (which in this context is bad).

Is there any way to listen for when a request is completed without calling `fetch(event.request)` manually?

For example:

```
// This doesn't work
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  event.request.then(function () {
    // do something here
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean the script is loading asynchronously? What are you doing on the front end with this?

Comment: @philnash: I think I was just getting confused by the waterfall: http://i.imgur.com/S3eU293.png

I made this change and the perceived load time of the website sped up by 35% (2.0s -> 1.3s). Still not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to ensure that your entire series of actions are performed before the response is returned to the page, you should respond with the entire promise chain, not just the initial promise returned by fetch.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
    // The fetch() is complete and response is available now.
    // response.ok will be true if the HTTP response code is 2xx
    // Make sure you return response at the end!
    return response;
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // This will be triggered if the initial fetch() fails,
    // e.g. due to network connectivity. Or if you throw an exception
    // elsewhere in your promise chain.
    return error;
  }));
});
```

Comment: Yeah I'm not worried about that. I'm literally just monitoring, not modifying anything, so it doesn't really make any difference. Thanks :)